# get the name of selected harness branch in catia electrical harness

Tags: vba, catia

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UfSg.png)I am trying to create macro which can show the defected harness branches name in Catia electrical Assy. I tried with below code. but I am getting name as "selction0()". if am adding "selection1.Item(1).Value.Name" it is showing only part number instead of electrical branch name.

```vb
Sub CATMain()

Dim productDocument1 As ProductDocument
Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim selection1 As Selection
Set selection1 = productDocument1.Selection

selection1.Search "CATElectricalSearch.Branchable.IsResultOK=FALSE,all"

Dim brnch As String
 brnch = selection1.Name
msgbox brnch

End Sub
```

Comment: If you using _CATScript_ please use tag _vba_ instead of _vbscript_.

Comment: Have you selected (by searching) the correct elements? What type does these elements have (using e.g. `.Type` of `TypeName`)? Which name do you want to get? (show tree and/or properties window)

Comment: yes, it is selecting what I want to select that is "Branchable". I added image for more clarity. when use "selection1.Item(1).Type ". it is showing "product".

Comment: Please select one _brachable_ feature manual and test again the type (and TypeName). If you still get a product, a guess these features are not accessible per macro.

Comment: I tried with this "msgbox Osel.Item(1).Value.Name", except those branchable  features if i selecting any other it is working fine. but not working on branchable  features